# How to show concrete page(fragment) of ViewPager when Activity first open?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, fragment

I have an Activity with ViewPager which has 3 Fragments (3 pages).

**How do I show concrete page(fragment) when Activity first opens?!**

For example lets say 2-d or 3-d page (fragment).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ViewPager `setCurrentItem` method that takes page index as parameter to programmatically change active page(fragment)

```
  mPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

[ViewPager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Thats what I wanted!